# AutoMapper map long? to string

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two classes, a ViewModel and a Dto, that are basically identical except that the Dto has a field 'readonly long? Phone;' while the ViewModel has the a property 'string Phone { get; set; }'.

The only way I've found to get AutoMapper to work is by changing the ViewModel Property to a backing property:

```
    public long? Phone { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumberString
    {
        get
        {
            var srv = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IPhoneNumberService>();
            return srv.GetFormattedPhoneNumber(Phone);
        }
        set
        {
            var srv = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IPhoneNumberService>();
            Phone = srv.GetLongPhoneNumber(value);
        }
    }
```

And then in AutoMapper, have a gigantic line to call the constructor:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<MyViewModel, MyDto>()
        .ConstructUsing(src => new MyDto(
            src.Phone
    /* ...Some ~30 other parameters here... */))
        .ReverseMap();
});
```

...There must be a better way to do this? I've tried these:

```
.ForSourceMember(x => x.PhoneNumberString, opt => opt.DoNotValidate())
```

and

```
.ForMember(x => x.PhoneNumberString, opt => opt.Ignore())
```

and

```
.ForMember(viewModel => viewModel.Phone, options => options.MapFrom<PhoneNumberResolver>());//PhoneNumberResolver implements IValueResolver<ProspectMaintenanceViewModel, ProspectMaintenanceDto, long?>
```

Which all give 'Core.DTO.MyDto needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args.' when trying to map, and:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Phone, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => 5))
```

Which gives 'System.ArgumentException: 'Expression must be writeable' when trying to configure AutoMapper.

Is there some way I can make AutoMapper understand that it can entirely ignore PhoneNumberString (or, even better, some way by which I can make it map long? to string so I don't need the backing property) without having to use the dto's constructor?

> Is there any special reason that requires your DTO to not have a default constructor?

I have all my fields as readonly so that I can include a constructor that modifies (e.g. 'Description = description?.Trim();') and validates (e.g. 'if (Phone.HasValue && Phone.ToString().Length != 10) throw ...') the parameters. This way I can ensure that the Dto, being a value object, is always in a valid state.

Comment: Is there any special reason that requires your DTO to *not* have a default constructor? I would just add a default constructor to my data class and trust automapper to fill in all the fields except the ignored ones (the `opt.Ignore()` solution).

Comment: Also, you could look into the `MapFrom` documentation (`ResolveUsing` in older Automapper versions) to get rid of the `PhoneNumberString` backing property. This feature allows you to map members of different types (or names) by using external conversion code.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the problem. It has absolutely nothing to do with what I thought it did. Mapping map long? to string **works out of the box**.

The problem I had was with an entirely different property.

I had the following structure:

```
public class MyDto
{
    public readonly AddressDto BillingAddress;
    public readonly AddressDto ShippingAddress;
    public readonly long? Phone;
    ...
}
public class AddressDto
{
    public readonly string Country;
    public readonly string SubnationalEntity;
    ...
}
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string BillingAddressCountry { get; set; }
    public string BillingAddressSubnationalEntity { get; set; }
    public string ShippingAddressCountry { get; set; }
    public string ShippingAddressSubnationalEntity { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

It worked once I changed it to the following:

```
public class MyDto
{
    public readonly AddressDto BillingAddress;
    public readonly AddressDto ShippingAddress;
    public readonly long? Phone;
    ...
}
public class AddressDto
{
    public readonly string Country;
    public readonly string SubnationalEntity;
    ...
}
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string AddressViewModel BillingAddress { get; set; }
    public string AddressViewModel ShippingAddress { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    ...
}
public class AddressViewModel
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string SubnationalEntity { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## 1) Mapping to readonly field

So you have a `Dto` class:

```cs
public class Dto
{
    public readonly long? PhoneNumber;
}
```

And then you are trying to force AutoMapper to do this:

```cs
var dto = new Dto();
dto.PhoneNumber = 123; // <== ERROR! A readonly field cannot be assigned to.
```

AutoMapper cannot write to readonly fields or properties. In matter of fact you neither. Either turn your field into a property with `protected` or `private` setter:

```cs
public class Dto
{
    public long? PhoneNumber { get; private set; }
}
```

or make it a regular field by removing the `readonly` keyword:

```cs
public class Dto
{
    public long? PhoneNumber;
}
```

## 2) Custom value resolving

#### ASP.NET MVC

Use a [`ValueResolver`](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html):

```cs
public class StringPhoneNumberResolver : IValueResolver<Dto, ViewModel, string>
{
    private readonly IPhoneNumberService _phoneNumberService;

    public StringPhoneNumberResolver()
    {
        _phoneNumberService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IPhoneNumberService>();
    }

    public string Resolve(Dto source, ViewModel destination, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return _phoneNumberService.GetFormattedPhoneNumber(source.PhoneNumber);
    }
}
```

You should know that generally it is an anti-pattern to have service injection in a DTO or `IValueResolver`. AutoMapper should be dumb and all kind of injections and so on should be handled elsewhere. That being said, here is the AutoMapper configuration:

```cs
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Dto, ViewModel>()
        .ForMember(viewModel => viewModel.PhoneNumber, options =>
            options.MapFrom<StringPhoneNumberResolver>());
});
```

If you want to reverse the process of `long` ==> `string` to `string` ==> `long` simply add another value resolver:

```cs
public class LongPhoneNumberResolver : IValueResolver<ViewModel, Dto, long?>
{
    private readonly IPhoneNumberService _phoneNumberService;

    public LongPhoneNumberResolver()
    {
        _phoneNumberService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IPhoneNumberService>();
    }

    public long? Resolve(ViewModel source, Dto destination, long? destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return _phoneNumberService.GetLongPhoneNumber(source.PhoneNumber);
    }
}
```

#### .NET Core

If you would operate in .NET Core environment, which fully supports `IServiceCollection` integration, you should add this AutoMapper configuration:

```cs
serviceCollection.AddAutoMapper(config =>
{
    config.CreateMap<Dto, ViewModel>()
        .ForMember(viewModel => viewModel.PhoneNumber, options =>
            options.MapFrom<StringPhoneNumberResolver>());
}, typeof(Startup));
```

and then have `IPhoneNumberServce` automagically injected into value resolver:

```cs
public StringPhoneNumberResolver(IPhoneNumberService phoneNumberService)
{
    _phoneNumberService = phoneNumberService;
}
```

For dependency injection I used [automapper.extensions.microsoft.dependencyinjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/automapper.extensions.microsoft.dependencyinjection/) package.